# Determine the following limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to ∞}\arctan(n!)$$
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n\pi^2)\ln(1+n)}{n}$$

I don't have a solution for these limits. If you could please give a hint to me, it would be appreciated.

Comment: $\arctan(\infty) = {\pi\over 2}$

Comment: What did you try, at least for the second one?

Comment: $\frac{sin(nπ^2)ln(1+n)}{n}$ $\leq$ $\frac{ln(1+n)}{n}$, 
 $\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}$$\frac{ln(1+n)}{n}$ and if we apply DHL rule we get 0

Comment: for the real function $f(x)=\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}$

Comment: @argiriskar Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition

$$\arctan n!\to\frac{\pi}2$$

and
$$\frac{\sin(n\pi^2)\ln(1+n)}{n}\to 0$$

indeed by squeeze theorem

$$0\le\left|\frac{\sin(n\pi^2)\ln(1+n)}{n}\right|\le \frac{\ln(1+n)}{n}\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

As you know, $\arctan(n) \to \frac{\pi}{2}, n \to \infty$ hence your first limit is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$
As for your second limit, let's consider $\frac{\ln (1 + n)}{n}$ this sequence $\to 0$ because $\ln$ increases much slower than a linear function. So, your second limit is a product of the bounded function $\sin$ and the infinitesimally small function, which $\to 0$. Thus, your second limit is equal to $0$.

Comment: I thought of this too. Thank you very much!

Comment: @argiriskar you're welcome!